# function within function in PHP

Tags: php

Im having trouble getting a function within a function working, do you think what I have below is done rigth? Im not getting the expected results, if you could shed some light on functions within functions i would appriciete it.

thanks

```
function test1 ()

{

    global x;

    $x=123;

    function test2()
    {
    echo $x;
    }

    test2();

}
```

Comment: What is your expected result? This construct makes hardly sense. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, but the scope of `test2()` is limited.  For example, this works:

```
[wally@zf ~]$ cat y.php
<?php
function test1 ()
{
        global $x;
        $x=123;

        function test2()
        {
                global $x;
                echo $x;
        }

        test2();
}

test1();
?>
[wally@zf ~]$ php -f y.php
123[wally@zf ~]$
```

Comment: wallyk thank you for the insight, this indeed works now. can you explain why you require x to be redeclared once again as a global in the second function?

Comment: It's so that `$x` can be seen outside the respective functions.  If `$x=123` were set outside `test1()`, there would be no need for `test1()` to have `global $x`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just include it as another function outside the first function (test1)?  I'm having trouble picturing a use-case for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function test2 so there's no reason for it to echo $x.

besides, you should construct the function outside, there's no added value in this case.